# Need the output of 2 commands in same line & need to add columns

Tags: shell

I just started to learn shell scripting and currently wrote a small shell script as below.

Problem:

1. Output for this command is coming (like first command is running first and giving the output & second command then sending the output below to first one. I want to have output for both the commands in same line.
2. I want to organize the script. Where I want the output should come in row & columns and if I can add the date as well, since I am gonna add this script in cronjob which will generate the file in every 5 minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash
MEM=`"$IPATH"/cli iedge list | grep "Registration ID" | cut -f6`;
PORT=`"$IPATH"/cli iedge list | grep "Ongoing Calls" | cut -f6`;
echo `date "+%F %T"`",$MEM,$PORT" >> $IFILE;
```

Its giving the output at least better then before, however I wanted to know if we can do it like the way I attached sample format?

```
IPATH='/usr/local/nextone/bin';
IFILE='/root/vport.csv';
MEM=`"$IPATH"/cli iedge list | egrep "Registration ID|Ongoing Calls" | cut -f6`;
echo `date "+%F %T"`",$MEM" >> $IFILE;
```

With this I am getting the below output:

```
 Registration ID                                           SONUS_01
  Ongoing Calls                                             0 (0:0)
```

However I want this output, if possible:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|      Date/Time     | REGISTRATION ID | Ongoing Calls

|2.23 Pm, 1 Jun-2015 | SONUS_01        | 0 (0:0)
------------------------------------------------------
```

Output after New comment from WalterA..

Now i can see something i wanted to see like as below.

```
| Registration ID | SONUS_02      | Ongoing Calls | 1 (0:1)
```

However this is the predefined value which we assigned for Single Endpoint. We want that this script should run and capture all the endpoint name "REGISTRATION ID" & "ONGOING CALLS" and from there the output can came.

Below command if i run on the server its giving me the output below and i can send the output of below command in particular file etc

*# cli iedge list | egrep "Registration ID|Ongoing Calls" >> nitin.csv*
*cli iedge list is the command which give the output for all the endpoint configured on SBC*

New Script look like below.

```
MEM=`"$IPATH"/cli iedge list | egrep "Registration ID|Ongoing Calls" | cut -f6`;
```

R="Registration ID"; S="SONUS_02"; C="Ongoing Calls"; N="1 (0:1)"; printf "| %-15s | %-13s | %-13s | %-21s |" "$R" "$S" "$C" "$N"
echo `date "+%F %T"`",$MEM" >> $IFILE;

Comment: What is the problem? Doesn't grep work (maybe cli sends to stderr and you need 2>&1) of do you have many hits with the grep but always the same number of ports and mem?

Comment: 1) ) Currently the output is coming like as below. which is not in same line,

(Registration ID                                           SONUS_02)
(Ongoing Calls                                             1 (0:1))

3) I want them to come in same line with raw & columns also if i can add the field name.
------------------------------------------------------------
| Registration ID | Endpoint Name | Ongoing Calls | Number of calls Active|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Registration ID |    SONUS_02    |  Ongoing Calls |   1 (0:1) |

Comment: Please put your exanples in your question where you can format them and include an example of the input by running `"$IPATH"/cli iedge list | egrep "Registration ID|Ongoing Calls"`. Actually, you can simplify your question by using an inputfile: `MEM=$(grep "Registration ID" inputfile | cut -f6)`.

Comment: I just updated the question...now its only giving me the date please advise

Comment: Please ignore.. i made a mistake..It was suppose to be "egrep" not "pgrep"

Thanks for your help.

I Want them to be in in columns and if i can add the Field name above?

Comment: @NitinKapoor :  Your question is not clear. Sample input and output can make us understand the problem better.

Comment: Dear All...I am sorry for not be clear. I just adjusted my question as per suggestion. What i am getting after WalterA suggested and what i want to do... Can you please advise if its clear now?

Comment: Check your formatting (do not use backtics for multiple lines, use the `{}`).
Show the output of `$IPATH"/cli iedge list` . The `egrep`was not part of the solution, put a way to filter the cli output. You cut field 6, is that correct for both var's? Formatting could be something like `R="Registration ID"; S="SONUS_02"; C="Ongoing Calls"; N="1 (0:1)"; printf "| %-15s | %-13s | %-13s | %-21s |" "$R" "$S" "$C" "$N"`, put I can not verify it without sample input.

Comment: You have two questions here -- they should be asked as two separate questions, not munged into one. That way whoever wants to answer a question about output formatting doesn't need to deal with input parsing, and the inverse, and you can get voting/discussion on the best approach for each of the two individual parts. As it is, with the two questions put together, this is too broad.

Comment: Thanks WalterA Sir...I just updated with current script output and what we want to achieve.  Now i am getting bit closer for what i want to achieve.

Comment: Dear All,

Can anyone please help on this.